# Использование .ToList() с XDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, разметка

Есть вот такое выражение:

```
var ext =
                xDoc.XPathSelectElements("*//nodes")
                    .DescendantNodes().ToList();
```

И по нему есть несколько вопросов:

1) На выходе я получаю `List<XNode>`. Могу я его на ходу преобразовать в `List<XElement>` ? Пробовал различные вариации преобразований, но получаю ругань компилятора.

2)Можно ли получить не просто коллекцию `List<XElement>`, а ,допустим, `List<string,XElement>`, где string- это какой-нибудь из атрибутов XElement ?

Answer (score 3):

`XElement` - это наследник `XNode`, поэтому список узлов в список элементов можно преобразовать операцией `.OfType`:

```
var ext = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("*//nodes").DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>().ToList();
```

Но в вашем случае проще с самого начала выбрать `Descendants()` вместо `DescendantNodes()`:

```
var ext = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("*//nodes").Descendants().ToList();
```

А еще проще можно сделать вот так:

```
var ext = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("*//nodes//*").ToList();
```

Или вот так:

```
var ext = xDoc.Root.Descendants("nodes").Descendants().ToList();
```

---

По второму вопросу - такой коллекции как `List<string, XElement>`, не существует. Поэтому не вполне понятно что вы пытаетесь получить.

Возможно, вам нужен словарь:

```
var ext = xDoc.Root.Descendants("nodes").Descendants().ToDictionary(x => (string)x.Attribute("name"));
```

Или Lookup:

```
var ext = xDoc.Root.Descendants("nodes").Descendants().ToLookup(x => (string)x.Attribute("name"));
```

Comment: Спасибо, а что-нибудь по второму вопросу, можете написать?

Comment: Я, просто, хочу привязать коллекцию элементов XML к DataGridView, и отображать атрибуты в колонках, а при дабл клике, грузить этот XElement в спец форму.

Comment: А Lookup, как я понимаю работает подобно словарю? Вроде в Lookup нельзя добавлять ничего, что минус, так как при добавлении новых ухлов, его приется пересоздавать=(

Comment: Да, так и есть. Но там для одного ключа может быть несколько значений.